# R Automatically name results of Loop

Tags: r, loops, sample

I have a list of dataframes:

```
df_DJF = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
df_JJA = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,20,rep=TRUE)))
df_MAM = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,25,rep=TRUE)))
df_SON = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,15,rep=TRUE)))

df_list = list(df_DJF, df_JJA, df_MAM, df_SON)
```

I want to randomly choose 80% of each the dataframe. I can do that manually by doing this and using the sample_size as row index.

```
sample_size = floor(0.8*nrow(df_DJF))
picked_DJF = sample(seq_len(nrow(df_DJF)), size = sample_size)
```

My problem is that I have very many df with different number of rows. So I want to automatize this process. In the end I want to have 4 sample sizes with the correct number in it. The names of the sample_sizes should be:

```
samplenames = paste("sample_size", c("DJF", "JJA", "MAM", "SON"), sep = "_")
```

Same for the "picked"...it should be picked_DJF and so on...

Comment: Look up `assign`, which seems to work ok for loops but less well for `apply` functions

Comment: I tried assign already, but I ended up just getting one single sample...can you please show me how to do this?

Comment: for(x in samplenames){assign(x,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE))}

Answer (score 2):

Keep using lists, not `assign`. Set your `names(df_list) = c("DJF", "JJA", "MAM", "SON")`, then use the same names for subsequent lists, like a `picked` list.

```
# for a single sample size
picked = lapply(df_list, function(x) x[sample(1:nrow(x), size = floor(0.8 * nrow(x))), ])
```

Using `lapply` will keep the names of the original list so you don't have to worry about it.

For multiple sample sizes from each of the data frames, you could create a nested list with a nested `lapply`:

```
names(df_list) = c("DJF", "JJA", "MAM", "SON")
sample_prop = list(s1 = 0.2, s2 = 0.4, s3 = 0.6, s4 = 0.8)
picked = lapply(df_list, function(df) lapply(sample_prop, function(sp) {
  df[sample(nrow(df), size = floor(sp * nrow(df))), ]
}))

# then access individual data frames with `$` or `[[`
picked$JJA$s3
#    X1  X2
# 17 70 128
# 7  94 121
# 1  57 125
# 8  32  75
# 9  15   8
# 19 58  15
# 20 55  17
# 10 42  15
# 4  51  67
# 12 89  13
# 2  74  50
# 14 77  36
```

To divide a data frame in to "picked" and "unpicked", `split` makes sense. It already returns a `list`. This will give a triple-nested list result:

```
result = lapply(df_list, function(df) lapply(sample_prop, function(sp) {
  n_pick = floor(sp * nrow(df))
  n_unpick = nrow(df) - n_pick
  split(df, f = c(rep("picked", n_pick), rep("unpicked", n_unpick))[sample(nrow(df))])
}))

result$JJA$s3$unpicked
#     X1  X2
# 2   74  50
# 3   62  78
# 4   51  67
# 6  103  42
# 7   94 121
# 11  59  60
# 14  77  36
# 16  83  72
```

Comment: One more question. How can I get an "unpicked" list. I also want to have a list fo dataframes with the rows that didnt get picked. My original idea was to do Cal = df_DJF[picked,]
Val = df_DJF[-picked,]

Comment: See edits for splitting the data rather than just subsetting.